# FontAwesome instagram icon - colorized

Tags: css, font-awesome

Any one know how to show the FontAwesome icon for Instagram and style it to be shown with the new Instagram icon multi colors?
[New instagram icon](https://www.instagram-brand.com/)

Comment: you don't, use the image you linked to instead

Comment: Really?  A -1 for that Q?  Apparently it looks possible (although maybe difficult) from other answers.

Comment: Recreating images with css when you can use the image = time consuming and pointless, but whatever rocks your socks.

Answer (score 40):

I was trying to do the same. I found this is solution after several attempt.

```css
.fa.fa-instagram {
  color: transparent;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To have it as background, just keep the background parameters: .bg-instagram1 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}

Comment: this does not seem to work on mobile chrome or safari

Answer (score 8):

```
instagram {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%); 
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);    
}
```

Adding a CSS class like this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think you will get the exact color sheme but [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddd3o63k/)

```
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );  
    background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
    color:transparent; 
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
```

found [here](https://rainbowcoding.com/how-to-create-rainbow-text-in-html-css-javascript/) might help